# Measure max datetime per Id in Dax

Tags: powerbi, dax

Suppose that you have a table with two columns ("ID","DATETIME").
For each "ID" there are multiple rows with different datetimes.
I want to create a third column named "IS_LAST" which has a Boolean data type.
For each row I want to filter the table with the "ID" present in the row and want to check if the "DATETIME" in row is the latest. If yes, "IS_LAST" goes to TRUE else FALSE.

My tentative is: `IF(COUNTROWS(FILTER(TABLE, TABLE[ID] = [ID] && TABLE[DATETIME] > [DATETIME]) = 0)), TRUE, FALSE)`. But this gives TRUE for all rows.

Comment: Is this a calculated column or a measure? Do you have sample data and expected output?

Comment: It is a measure. For the sample data just create 20 rows 10 for each id ("001","002"). Just put random datetime for each row. I expect only one row for each Id to have "IS_LAST" with TRUE corresponding the max datetime row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
Is Last = 
 
VAR latest =  CALCULATE(MAX('Table'[time]), ALLEXCEPT('Table','Table'[id]))
RETURN
IF(SELECTEDVALUE('Table'[time]) = latest, TRUE())
```

Comment: The objective/idea is correct but the argument of SELECTEDCOLUMS gives error "Parameter is not the correct type". Am I doing something wrong with this measure?

Comment: Are you doing this in PowerBI desktop? Have you copied the code exactly? Are your table and columns names matching mine? Can you share your .pbix?

Comment: Yes, Im creating this in BI desktop. The only differences are the names of the table and variables but shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Is your time column a datetime datatype?

Comment: Sorry, I was using SELECTEDCOLUMNS instead. Now seems to work but all rows per id are False...

Comment: Without you sharing a .pbix, I am unable to help you debug what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Good stuff and you're welcome  :)